# I am trying to convert into scientific notation

Tags: tables, siunitx, booktabs

I am trying to convert the following table with scientific notation (e.g. e^-01), but it's not working. Here is a minimal working example for my thesis. Thank you very much for your help!

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\providecommand{\sci}[1]{\protect\ensuremath{\times 10^{\StrSubstitute[0]{#1}{e}{}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Gene expression for final candidate genes}\label{tab:final_expression}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llcccc}
\toprule
& Gene & {$\log(FC)$} & {\textit{t}-stat} & {\textit{p}-value} & {Adj.\textit{p}-value}\\
\midrule
Amplification & PIK3CA & 0.51 & 4.09 & 3.97e-04 & 1.32e-03 \\
& PTK2 & 1.21 & 6.20 & 1.74e-06 & 1.03e-05 \\  
& PTK2 & 0.46 & 4.49 & 1.38e-04 & 5.13e-04 \\ 
\addlinespace
 Deletion & FGFR2 & -3.12 & -8.93 & 2.97e-09 & 3.98e-08 \\
 & FGFR2 & -2.52 & -7.92 & 2.85e-08 & 2.77e-07 \\ 
 & FGFR2 & -2.51 & -8.03 & 2.20e-08 & 2.22e-07 \\ 
 & FGFR2 & -2.47 & -7.83 & 3.48e-08 & 3.31e-07 \\ 
 & FGFR2 & -2.46 & -7.14 & 1.74e-07 & 1.37e-06 \\ 
 & FGFR2 & -2.45 & -7.72 & 4.47e-08 & 4.13e-07 \\ 
 & FGFR2 & -2.45 & -7.51 & 7.25e-08 & 6.31e-07 \\ 
 & FGFR2 & -2.43 & -7.71 & 4.59e-08 & 4.23e-07 \\ 
 & FGFR2 & -2.42 & -7.65 & 5.32e-08 & 4.81e-07 \\ 
 & FGFR2 & -2.39 & -7.49 & 7.66e-08 & 6.63e-07 \\ 
 & FGFR2 & -2.20 & -6.70 & 5.04e-07 & 3.50e-06 \\ 
 & FGFR2 & -0.94 & -4.39 & 1.83e-04 & 6.60e-04 \\
 & FAM101B & -0.93 & -6.11 & 2.17e-06 & 1.26e-05 \\ 
 & P2RY5 & -0.89 & -5.58 & 8.46e-06 & 4.22e-05 \\
 & P2RY5 & -0.89 & -7.71 & 4.59e-08 & 4.23e-07 \\
 & PDE2A & -0.55 & -3.99 & 5.13e-4 & 1.66e-3 \\
 & VPS53 & -0.63 & -5.71 & 6.03e-06 & 3.12e-05 \\
 \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you expand a bit on 'not working'?

Comment: Is `\( e^{-01}\)` what you're looking for?

Comment: You also might want to check out the siunitx package some time.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: What's the purpose of reporting explicitly the minuscule p-values and adjusted p-values? Every single coefficient is significant at the 99.8% level and, in many cases, even the 99.99% level. What is the reader supposed to take away from being shown the exact p-values? Surely the only sensible inference must be, in every single case, that "the null hypothesis that the coefficient is zero must be rejected", right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `siunitx` and its `table-format` key. You don't have to define a `\sci` command. Also I added the `caption`package, to have a sensible spacing between caption and table.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center, exponent-product=\cdot}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \caption{Gene expression for final candidate genes}\label{tab:final_expression}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll*{2}{S[table-format=-1.2]}*{2}{S[table-format=1.2e-2]}}
    \toprule
                  & Gene & {$\log(FC)$} & {\textit{t}-stat} & {\textit{p}-value} & {Adj.\textit{p}-value} \\
    \midrule
    Amplification & PIK3CA & 0.51 & 4.09 & 3.97e-04 & 1.32e-03 \\
                  & PTK2 & 1.21 & 6.20 & 1.74e-06 & 1.03e-05 \\
                  & PTK2 & 0.46 & 4.49 & 1.38e-04 & 5.13e-04 \\
    \addlinespace
    Deletion & FGFR2 & -3.12 & -8.93 & 2.97e-09 & 3.98e-08 \\
                  & FGFR2 & -2.52 & -7.92 & 2.85e-08 & 2.77e-07 \\
                  & FGFR2 & -2.51 & -8.03 & 2.20e-08 & 2.22e-07 \\
                  & FGFR2 & -2.47 & -7.83 & 3.48e-08 & 3.31e-07 \\
                  & FGFR2 & -2.46 & -7.14 & 1.74e-07 & 1.37e-06 \\
                  & FGFR2 & -2.45 & -7.72 & 4.47e-08 & 4.13e-07 \\
                  & FGFR2 & -2.45 & -7.51 & 7.25e-08 & 6.31e-07 \\
                  & FGFR2 & -2.43 & -7.71 & 4.59e-08 & 4.23e-07 \\
                  & FGFR2 & -2.42 & -7.65 & 5.32e-08 & 4.81e-07 \\
                  & FGFR2 & -2.39 & -7.49 & 7.66e-08 & 6.63e-07 \\
                  & FGFR2 & -2.20 & -6.70 & 5.04e-07 & 3.50e-06 \\
                  & FGFR2 & -0.94 & -4.39 & 1.83e-04 & 6.60e-04 \\
                  & FAM101B & -0.93 & -6.11 & 2.17e-06 & 1.26e-05 \\
                  & P2RY5 & -0.89 & -5.58 & 8.46e-06 & 4.22e-05 \\
                  & P2RY5 & -0.89 & -7.71 & 4.59e-08 & 4.23e-07 \\
                  & PDE2A & -0.55 & -3.99 & 5.13e-4 & 1.66e-3 \\
                  & VPS53 & -0.63 & -5.71 & 6.03e-06 & 3.12e-05 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I tried to center the last 4 columns without any success. Just so I understand: the "-" simply instructs latex to take it as being part of the number's value, so everything aligns properly, right?

Comment: That is correct. The columns are centred if you add `\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}` in the preamble, else they're aligned on the decimal dot. Do you need the `0` in the exponents?

Comment: I don't need the 0, but it is the output generated by a R program that I wrote. I'm sorry if I don't see it, but I would like the numbers to align to each other, and the entire S column to align to the column titles. Is that possible (e.g. t-stat)? Thank you! :)

Comment: The numbers are all aligned by the decimal dot, and centred in their columns. The problem for the last two columns came from the spurious digit for the exponent. I changed the code to take care of that. I took the opportunity to replace `×` by a `·`. It also could be a medium  unbreakable space. If there remains a problem, let me know.